# Aggregate joined table titles into comma separated string, sorted by time created

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to select a column that is an aggregation of all of the joined rows' titles, ordered by the joined rows' created_at time.  However, whatever the `ORDER BY` in the `INNER JOIN`, the string of titles always remains the same regardless.

Here's my query:

```
                SELECT
                    id AS assignment_id,
                    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(ARRAY_AGG(_outlets.title))), ',', '') AS outlets,
                FROM
                    assignments
                LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            assignment_outlets.created_at AS created_at,
                            outlet_id,
                            assignment_id,
                            title
                        FROM assignment_outlets
                        INNER JOIN outlets ON outlets.id = assignment_outlets.outlet_id
                        ORDER BY assignment_outlets.created_at DESC
                    )
                    AS _outlets
                    ON _outlets.assignment_id = assignments.id
                GROUP BY assignments.id;
```

I'm trying to get the result `'title1,title2,title3,title4,...'`, where they are ordered from left to right as oldest to newest.

Comment: Can you post sample outputs of what you are returning and what you would like to return?

Comment: "Comma separated array" - I have to note it down! ;)

Comment: Something like `..., array_to_string(array_agg(distinct _outlets.title order by _outlets.created_at desc), ',') ...`

Comment: @Abelisto That looks right.  I have this now `ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT _outlets.title ORDER BY _outlets.created_at), ',', '') AS outlets,` but I get this error: `LINE 4: ...STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT _outlets.title ORDER BY _outlets.c...     ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list`

Comment: Yes, sorry, my fail. However you should to clarify how `distinct title` and `order by created_at` correlates, f.i. `(title1, 1), (title2, 2), (title1, 3)` what is desired order?

Comment: @Abelisto I'm going for the output `title1,title2,title3,title4,...` where the order is by ascending timestamp.  The time is simply to order the titles correctly, as the order is significant to the order in which all of the listed outlets joined (oldest -> newest)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `string_agg`, and there's no need for a subquery:

```
SELECT a.id AS assignment_id, string_agg(o.title, ',' ORDER BY ao.created_at DESC) AS outlets
FROM assignments a
LEFT JOIN assignment_outlets ao ON (ao.assignment_id = i.id)
LEFT JOIN outlets o ON (o.id = ao.outlet_id)
GROUP BY a.id;
```